# When exactly should the transition action be executed on hierarchical state machine?

Tags: uml, modeling, state-machine

Given this HSM example model - http://www.embedded.com/design/system-integration/4008251/8/A-crash-course-in-UML-state-machines-Part-2 - I'm wondering what should be the RIGHT moment of executing transition action. Let's say that this machine is in its initial state S211 and event G is dispatched (S21 -> S1) - let's assume that there's some action for this event. Should the sequence be like that:

exit to the least common ancestor (S) - transition action - entry to destination state (S1) - init actions of target...

or maybe like this:

exit to the source state of transition (S21) - transition action - exit to the least common ancestor (S) - entry to destination state (S1) - init action of target

?

In short - is the transition action associated with the "source of transition" or the "least common ancestor"?

The example with description at wikipedia is too trivial to give these details... The UML specs seem to suggest the LCA answer to be the right one, but I'm not sure.

Thx in advance (;

Answer (score 1):

Automata theory suggests that the action does not occur in either the source or the target.  But neither does automata theory generally consider hierarchical states.  So yes, the LCA is as good a theoretical assumption as any for a transition action.

However, the state-machine code devised by Miro Samek (QHSM) actually performs the transition action within the source state.  Please understand, this is not either a problem or a flaw.

As any particular implementation is concerned, all that matters is that the transition action occurs in a consistent way.  That is the case with Miro's code.

If for whatever reason you really need the transition action to occur in the LCA or target state, you could use "extended state" to achieve the result.  But in practice, it really isn't ever necessary.

Comment: I know Miro's implementation does the action in the source state, but I was just wondering what's the proper/right approach according to UML- the lecture of the standard did not give me a clear answer...